# Compare date values "instantly" on user input

Tags: javascript, html, date, input

This question might be similar to this other question:

[HTML Comparing 2 Dates with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33713474/html-comparing-2-dates-with-javascript)

But I don't want  to use a `button`, simply make it instant.

I have 2 inputs of type `date` and I want to compare between them.

```html
<div>
  <label style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';">Select a date.</label>
  <br><br>
  <span style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';">Since</span>&nbsp;
  <input type="date" name="since"  id="since" required="required" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <span style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';">Until</span>&nbsp;
  <input type="date" name="until" id="until" required="required" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';"/>
  <br><br>
  <button style="font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Segoe UI';" onclick="Validate()">COMPARE THIS</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function Validate(){
    var date1 = new Date(document.getElementById('since').value);
    var date2 = new Date(document.getElementById('until').value);
  
    if(date2 < date1) {

        alert('The date cannot be less than the first date that you selected');
        return false;

    }else{
        alert("It's OK");
        return true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now the condition works perfectly, It compares the 2 dates and shows an error if the 2nd date is less than the first date. But this is using a button to trigger the comparison.

**Is it possible to compare the input dates without a button to trigger the comparison?** And using the `HTMLSelectElement.setCustomValidity()` method?

Comment: I would recommend you moment.js, its very popular library `date1.isBefore(date2)` returns boolean

Comment: how is there any php involved? I'll remove the tag

Comment: _"without a button that do the work"_ - yes, set an onKeyDown (or keyup..) listener on both inputs that calls `validate()`. But then the message _should not_ be an alert, but a message, and/or a red border around the inputs.

Comment: @Jeff. Is ok If I type the date, but if I only select the dates It's not show a message error.

Comment: `But I don't want to use a button, simply make it instant.` as soon as what ?

Comment: @Deda—that comment is completely irrelevant to the question asked, which really has nothing to do with Dates *per se*.

Comment: Your issue is that you can't easily determine when to do the comparison. You have to wait until you know the user has finished their input before doing anything, then wait until both inputs are complete before comparing. Also, you don't want to annoy the user with validation messages when they're only part way through data entry. Getting all that right takes a lot of work if you want to do it automatically (and has likely been well covered in SO over the years), a button greatly simplifies things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the onchange event to do this. I modified your snippet a little and put in a simple condition for when NOT to validate. You can adjust it to be more sophisticated.

```html
<div>
  <label style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';">Select a date.</label>
  <br><br>
  <span style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';">Since</span>&nbsp;
  <input onchange="Validate()" type="date" name="since"  id="since" required="required" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;

  <span style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';">Until</span>&nbsp;
  <input onchange="Validate()" type="date" name="until" id="until" required="required" style="font-family: 'Segoe UI';"/>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function Validate(){
    var input1 = document.getElementById('since').value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById('until').value;
  if(input1 != "" && input2 != ""){
      var date1 = new Date(input1);
      var date2 = new Date(input2);

      if(date2 < date1) {

          alert('The date cannot be less than the first date that you selected');
          return false;

      }else{
          alert("It's OK");
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful about which event you use with `<input type="date">` to avoid unintended consequences. The `input` and `change` events may fire as soon as the user enters any digit in the last empty section of the date (not necessarily consistent across browsers due to spotty support for `<input type="date">`).

For example (in Chrome), if the user enters "12" as the month, "31" as the date, and then enters a "2" in the year (with the intention of entering "2018"), the `input` and `change` events will fire as soon as the "2" is entered and in your scenario the validation function will then compare "12/31/0002" with the other date before the user finishes entering the year (and this will happen repeatedly as the user attempts to enter the remaining year digits). You may be able to work around this gracefully depending on how you notify the user of the validation results, but it will not be pretty if you use `alert()`.

For this reason, it may be safer to use an event like `blur` to trigger your validation comparison. Something like:

```js
const since = document.querySelector('#since');
const until = document.querySelector('#until');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const compareDates = () => {
  const sval = since.value;
  const uval = until.value;
  if (sval && uval && (uval < sval)) {
    message.innerHTML = 'The "Until" date must come after the "Since" date.';
  } else {
    message.innerHTML = '';
  }
};

since.addEventListener('blur', compareDates);
until.addEventListener('blur', compareDates);
```

```css
#message {
  margin: 8px 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="since">Since</label>
<input type="date" name="since" id="since" required>
<label for="until">Until</label>
<input type="date" name="until" id="until" required>
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Using alerts like this traps the user in a never-ending loop if they go back to the first input. A blur event fires on the second input, displaying the alert. As soon as it's dismissed, another blur event is triggered, etc. *ad infinitum*.

Comment: @RobG - good point. Edited the answer to remove the unnecessary alert notifying the user that the dates are 'OK', so now the snippet only triggers an alert if the "Until" date comes before the "Since" date (and avoids people getting stuck in an annoying loop when running the snippet).

Comment: Not fixed. Enter 2018-10-10 in first input, 2018-10-11 in second, go back to first and enter 2018-10-12, hit tab… ;-) Much easier to fix if you don't use an alert.

Comment: @RobG - whoa... still trying to wrap my head around why `alert()` interacts with the `focus` event that way. For now just adding it to my list of reasons why there is no good use for `alert()` except for checking something on the fly. Fixed the answer for real this time.